# HttpWebRequest not working although pure web service URL work

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest

I am calling a web service using C#, I am using HttpWebRequest to call the service, when I run the code there is no error and everything works as expected, although the response is always 0.

the web service should return the account balance, I am sending the correct parameters which are the username and password.

While debugging the code, if I copy the URL of the service and the posted parameter and paste them in the browser, I get the right response, but the request from C# is not working.

Here is the code:

```
public string sInvokeService()
{
    string sPostData = "userName=testITG&userPassword=MyPassword&By=nour";
    string sURL = "http://mobile.net.sa/sms/gw/Credits.php";
    HttpWebRequest oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
    oRequest.Method = "POST";
    oRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    oRequest.ContentLength = sPostData.Length;

    string sResponse = String.Empty;

    try
    {
         StreamWriter oStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(oRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        oStreamWriter.Write(sPostData);
        oStreamWriter.Close();

        StreamReader oStreamReader = new StreamReader(oRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        sResponse = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        oStreamReader.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
    }

    return sResponse;
}
```

**P.S**: As I said, if I copy the URL and the parameters and paste them directly in the browser (http://mobile.net.sa/sms/gw/Credits.php?userName=testITG&userPassword=MyPassword&By=nour), the response I get is "10" which is correct.

I want to know if I'm doing anything wrong, although there is another web service on that server that I am calling with this same code and it is working fine.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You would see that if your user/password contained characters that need UEL encoding as the browser would do that for you

Comment: Comparing a capture of a manual and code based request with Fiddler can be useful

Comment: How can you paste a POST into the browser?

Comment: There is no special characters in the username/passowrd, only English chars and numbers. And I have already done that but got nothing out of it, although I do not know what to look for, is there a specific thing in mind to compare in fiddler?

Comment: @spender the web service can be requested using GET/POST, and I have already tried both in the code.

Comment: @KarimAG: You capture the working request and the not working request in Fiddler. You select both, right-click and choose `Compare`. You then fix your broken request so it exactly matches the working one. My guess: You forgot to add a `User-Agent` header or expected `Cookie` header.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you paste the url in your browse it make a GET request not a POST. You need to specify that the method is post and pass your credential on the url (this must be the usrl: http://mobile.net.sa/sms/gw/Credits.php?serName=testITG&userPassword=MyPassword&By=nour) in your HttpWebRequest.